# Center video in portrait mode

Tags: java, android

I have a app that show's videos in a videoview.

When I have my app in landscape mode the video's show fullscreen which is good.
When I put my videoview in Portrait mode the width of the video is the width of the screen, en the height is scaling good.

The problem here is that the videoview is showing on the top of the screen. I want it to show on the middle of the screen( centering).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_custom_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/error_console"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <!--  webview will be put in the next framelayout -->

        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

       <VideoView
           android:id="@+id/surface_vie"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

How do I align my videoview in the center in portrait mode?

Comment: perhaps android:layout_centerInParent="true"'? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerInParent

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your VideoView

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: Then i'll get Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_centerInParent

Comment: Switch it into a RelativeLayout.

Comment: @RobertVerkerk - If you don't like an answer, you should comment on it or downvote it, not flag it for deletion. Flags should be reserved for things which clearly aren't attempts to answer, or things which consist of nothing more than a link.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I didn't flag it

Comment: @RobertVerkerk - Sorry, someone flagged it anonymously within the past hour and you had left a negative comment within the past hour, so I figured you were the person, seeing as only 19 people have seen this post so far.

Comment: @RobertVerkerk did you try changing it into a Relative Layout? It will work ;-)

Comment: @Tardo Will try tommorow, not at work pc atm. will comment/accept when/if it works:)